# Different syntaxes of import/export statements in typescript

Tags: typescript

There are different syntaxes of export and import statements in typescript.
I can write something like that:

```
export class MyClass {}
```

Then include that class in other file:

```
import {MyClass} from "./fileName"
```

But there are another way to write the same thing. Export:

```
class MyClass {}
export = MyClass;
```

Import:

```
import MyClass = require("./fileName");
```

My question is: which one of these methods I should use? Which one is more appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But there are another way to write the same thing. Export:

Module systems have existed before ES6. For example nodejs style `commonjs` and requirejs style `amd`. TypeScript supports these by providing its *own syntax extensions* specifically the `import =` and `export =` style import/exports.

For modern code prefer the ES6 style import / export i.e individual exports and `import / from` style syntax.